# Android Studio “class” or “interface” expected

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run an example of the book, and the book is writing the code in eclipse but when I create the class and constructor method I get the error that there should be an interface or class

```
public class Galaxy
{
String galaxyName;
int galaxySolarSystems;
int galaxyPlanets;
long galaxyColonies;
double galaxyLifeforms;
int galaxyFleets;
int galaxyStarships;
}

public Galaxy(String name, int solarSys, int planets)
{
galaxyName = name;
galaxySolarSystems = solarSys;
galaxyPlanets = planets;
galaxyColonies = 0;
galaxyLifeforms = 0;
galaxyFleets = 0;
galaxyStarships = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) **inside** the class, like this:

```
public class Galaxy
{
    String galaxyName;
    int galaxySolarSystems;
    int galaxyPlanets;
    long galaxyColonies;
    double galaxyLifeforms;
    int galaxyFleets;
    int galaxyStarships;

    public Galaxy(String name, int solarSys, int planets)
    {
        galaxyName = name;
        galaxySolarSystems = solarSys;
        galaxyPlanets = planets;
        galaxyColonies = 0;
        galaxyLifeforms = 0;
        galaxyFleets = 0;
        galaxyStarships = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i just got what is wrong with my code it's horrible i didn't catch this

Comment: No problem - we were all beginners once upon a time. Good luck!